# Ways around browser xss detection

Tags: web-browser, web-service, client-side

Most modern browsers will detect xss attempts (script code in the URL) and prevent execution. Are there any known standard ways around this or are xss attacks pretty much impossible now?

Comment: Never heard of XXS attack. Do you mean XSS instead?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I corrected that

Comment: I've testing it. For example, Google Chrome stops the execution of the script code unless you ran the browser with the --no-web-protection flag.

Comment: @begueradj It's a really small attack, apparently. Much less severe than XXL attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no standard ways around, but there are ways around. What exactly you have to do to get around will depend on the browser and on the version. On this link you can find some examples to get around the protection in Google Chrome:

http://blog.securitee.org/?p=37

The precondition on the examples at this blog post is that there are two GET parameters in the link which You can use for XSS. If an attacker would submit following for GET parameters a and b, Chrome will block it:

```
a=<script>alert(1)</script>&b=something
```

But if the a and b parameters are changed like this:

```
a=<script>void('&b=');alert(1);</script>
```

...Chrome will not detect the XSS. I tested it now and it works.

Comment: You should note, though, that it may not work in the next version of Chrome any longer...

Answer (score 3):

**XSS** attacks are still possible now, for this you can go through [OWASP's Top 10 Vulnerabilities Project 2013](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10), which is still a top 3 vulnerability.

But today modern browsers are very keen with **XSS**
and **Same-origin-policy** eventhough your website has no protection to this attacks.

In case of **XSS** every browsers are updated with **XSS Filters** in their newer versions.
Inorder to find XSS in your site you have to disable this filters and test for XSS vulnerabilities.

[Read this for disabling XSS Filter in IE and Firefox](https://www.phillips321.co.uk/2012/03/01/xss-browser-filters-disabling-it-for-app-testing/), and test for xss vulnerabilities.